# Responsive Bootstrap Carousel without Image Inside

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to implement a twitter bootstrap carousel. Except, I need to put content (containers, rows, spans, copy) in the slides rather than a big image. But, I do have a big image (1366x450) to display as the background of each slide, scalable/responsively.

I can't quite find a way to do this so that the background image scales correctly and the slide displays at the responsive sizes needed. I need quite a bit of padding top and bottom of the content.

Any ideas where to start?

Comment: How cross-browser does this need to be? You could investigate the use of `background-size` if CSS3 is an option.

Comment: @BenM It needs to be relatively cross browser (ie8+). I've had a look at background-size, but the problem is then that the slide isn't the right size in the first place as it will size to the content, not to the scale of the image dimensions, if that makes any since.

Comment: Have you thought about `@media` queries ? Using the same thing that Twitter Bootstrap uses.

Comment: And check [elliotjaystocks blog](http://elliotjaystocks.com/blog/better-background-images-for-responsive-web-design/) and the [Responsive-Images project on github](https://github.com/filamentgroup/Responsive-Images) but I think it's for `<img>` only.